# _[SOLVED]_ grub doesn't show the option for encrypted partition

Tags: boot, grub2, encryption

I installed ubuntu 22.04 LTS with the root partition encrypted. Now grub only allows me to boot my old (non-encrypted) ubuntu installation. how can I re-install grub so that it allows me to boot my current installation?
[image]

Thank you

PS: Is it possible to speed up grub startup somehow? because now it takes about ten seconds to load

Thank you again

simdll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED using a live installation of Ubuntu.